Custom Nginx Access Logs don't contain correct $remote_addr
so I've modified my nginx.conf file to use custom logging:
    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    # Define a custom log format with request protocol and without the $request part
    log_format custom_access 'StatusCode: $status - Remote IP: $remote_addr - User: $remote_user - '
        'Time (Local): [$time_local] - Request Method: $request_method - Request URI: $request_uri - '
        'Protocol: $server_protocol - Bytes Sent: $body_bytes_sent - '
        'Request Time: $request_time - Server Name: $server_name - Upstream Response Time: $upstream_response_time - '
        'Referer: "$http_referer" - User Agent: "$http_user_agent" - Forwarded For: "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    # Conditional logging - only log requests that do not have a 200 status code
    map $status $loggable {
            ~^[23] 0;
        default 1;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log custom_access if=$loggable;


After doing a test curl, copying the log in a text editor and adding line breaks to be able to read it better, it resulted in following:
StatusCode: 418
Remote IP: 172.18.0.21
User: -
Time (Local): [08/Aug/2024:09:25:42 +0000] 
Request Method: GET
Request URI: /
Protocol: HTTP/1.1
Bytes Sent: 4471
Request Time: 0.004
Server Name: genefit.cc
Upstream Response Time: 0.005
Referer: "-"
User Agent: "curl/7.74.0"
Forwarded For: "VPS_IP, 172.70.175.83"

As you can see, RemoteIP Contains the internal docker network ip of the container, not the IP of whoever made that request.
In Forwarded_For, it shows the real VPS IP and a random IP i'm not aware from what it is.
Questions:

How can i make remote_addr actually display the IP from which the request came from.
What is the Purpose of the IP in the second place of Forwarded For? (172.70.175.83)

I made the custom log because the default log wouldn't show the true remote ip, sadly this did not change with the custom logging in place.
Thanks in advance,
Toastlover
